# How to draw original diameter in form?

Tags: vb6

How i can to Draw Original diameter in form, with Pset method?

i want to draw a line like this : [see image](http://img7.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/9766/9766487df322afacfe09d3607b78ff5106188a2.jpg)

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a new vb project (Standard Executable) and copy/paste this code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.AutoRedraw = True
    Me.ScaleMode = vbPixels

End Sub

Private Sub DrawLine()

    Dim i As Single
    Dim Angle As Single

    Cls

    If Me.ScaleHeight = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Me.WindowState = vbMinimized Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Angle = Atn(Me.ScaleWidth / Me.ScaleHeight)
    For i = 0 To Sqr(Me.ScaleWidth * Me.ScaleWidth + Me.ScaleHeight * Me.ScaleHeight)

       PSet (i * Sin(Angle), i * Cos(Angle))

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()

    Call DrawLine

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub circleRoutine(aX As Single, aY As Single, Radius As Single, Steps As Single)
    Dim currAngleX As Single
    Dim i As Integer

    aX = aX - Radius * 1 / Steps

    For currAngleX = 0 To Rad(360) Step Steps
        aX = aX + Radius * Sin(currAngleX)
        aY = aY + Radius * Cos(currAngleX)
        Me.PSet (aX, aY)
    Next currAngleX
End Sub
```

Comment: What is "Rad(360)"? Vb6 cant not find it! Can you make a example of circleRoutine function? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DrawCircle(ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal Diameter As Single, ByVal PointsToDraw As Long)

    Dim Angle As Single

    For Angle = 0 To 2 * 3.14159 Step (2 * 3.14159) / PointsToDraw
        Me.PSet (X + Diameter * Sin(Angle) / 2, Y + Diameter * Cos(Angle) / 2), vbRed
    Next
End Sub
```

You should be aware that there is a Circle function that you can use instead. The code above could be replaced with:

```
Me.Circle (X,Y), Diameter / 2, vbRed
```

PSet is a relatively slow way to draw graphics, especially when there is already a built-in function you can use instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I put your code in a form, but it doesn't work. why? i edited my first post,please see it again. i want to draw a line, like that picture.

Comment: I changed the scalemode on the form to pixels and also set the forms's AutoRedraw to true.

Comment: Thanks. But i want to draw a line like that picture, in my first post. your code is for draw a circle!